# Google Calendar UI design like in flutter

Tags: user-interface, flutter

I want to know if there are anyway to make the UI animation of date in Google Calendar in flutter (the date of left hand side where it will be pinned until you swipe to a next day). I draw a blue box to indicate what I mean in the screenshot. 
Many thanks.
[Google Calendar Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnNY9.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [`side_header_list_view`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/side_header_list_view) plugin which is allows you to specify a side header for the list as shown in referance image.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! Definitely help me out.

Comment: this package is not working in Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.4)